# Importing Issues from Bitbucket to Github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Is anyone aware of a reasonable method to import existing Bitbucket issues to a Github account?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple scripts to do this:

- https://github.com/RonnyPfannschmidt/bitbucket_issue_migration - this uses both the BitBucket and Github APIs to retrieve issues from BitBucket and import them into Github.
- https://github.com/viniciusban/bitbucket_issues_to_github - this script imports issues which have been exported from BitBucket into Github.

I'm not aware of any ways to do this in the Github UI.

Comment: @Andrew Gillett posted another answer (that was deleted) suggesting https://github.com/jeffwidman/bitbucket-issue-migration is a better option, as the viniciusban/bitbucket_issues_to_github project hasn't been touched in several years.